# how to echo correct 2 variables in an anchor seperated by a slash in php

Tags: php, anchor

I have this variable:
`$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID;`

`$file` represents a file (like image.jpg)

What is the correct way to echo an anchor in which these 2 variables seperated by a / ?

Below is how i do it now and it does work fine but i think this is not the correct way to do it:

`echo "<a href='$dir/$file' target='_blank'></a>";`

Comment: What you've done is fine

Comment: It looks ok but you need some text within the body of the `<a>` tag for it to show up at all.

Comment: What is it that makes you think it isn't correct even though it works?

Comment: There are some answers now that may work for you as well, but they aren't any more valid that what you've already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
echo '<a href="' . $dir.'/' . $file.'" target="_blank"></a>';
```

or this

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $dir .'/'. $file; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: Why should he try this when the original works fine?

Comment: because using single quotes or direct html is faster than using double quotes

Comment: I doubt that single quotes with concatenation is really faster than double quotes with substitution. I'll bet it's parsed into identical code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done like this :

```
echo "<a href='" . $dir . "/" . $file . "' target='_blank'></a>";
```

Comment: personal opinion: single quotes for attributes give me the willies.  `echo '<a href="' . $dir . '/' . $file . '" target="_blank">Click Here</a>';`  for the win

Comment: This seems just like personal opinion.

Comment: @BradKent What difference does it make whether you use single or double quotes for attributes? HTML doesn't distinguish them.